# What are these characters? (Characters identified: 牧者所愛)

Tags: character-identification, calligraphy

I'm very rusty, and can't figure out the last character. Am I correct that the first 3 are 牧者所? Thank you so, so much!

[image: 4 characters]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first three characters are indeed 「牧者所」, with 「牧」 written with a corrupted 「攵」 which appears as 「文」. The last character is a reshuffled 「」, which in the current script is written as 「愛」.

---

<kbd>[戰國](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Warring_States_period)・[晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_(Chinese_state))
[金](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chinese_bronze_inscriptions)
[image: 㤅]
壺
[集成9734](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/?bh=9734&jgwfl=)</kbd><kbd>戰國・[楚](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chu_(state))
[簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bamboo_and_wooden_slips)
[image: 㤅]
六德・17
[郭店楚簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Guodian_Chu_Slips)</kbd>
<kbd>[隸定](https://zh.wikipedia.org/zh-hk/%E9%9A%B6%E5%AE%9A)
[image: 㤅]</kbd>

「愛」 ([Baxter-Sagart OC](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reconstructions_of_Old_Chinese#Baxter%E2%80%93Sagart_(2014)): **/*[q]ˤə[p]-s/**, *[benevolent] love*) was originally written as 「㤅」, comprised of semantic 「心」 (*heart*) and phonetic 「旡」 (**/*[k]ə[t]-s/**).

<kbd>[秦](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Qin_dynasty)
簡
[image]
54.51
[睡虎地秦簡](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuihudi_Qin_bamboo_texts)</kbd>
<kbd>[篆](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_seal_script)
[image]
[夊部](https://ctext.org/library.pl?if=gb&file=77390&page=52)
[說文解字](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shuowen_Jiezi)</kbd>
<kbd>隸定
[image]</kbd>

「夊」 was added later for no particular functionality. This was perhaps stylistic, and happened in several characters right below a component with the shape of a person. For reference, [「旡」 depicts a kneeling person with an open mouth](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian?kaiOrder=5432).

<kbd>[西漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Western_Han)
[隸](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clerical_script)
[image]
[老子甲](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tao_Te_Ching#Mawangdui_and_Guodian_texts)115
[馬王堆帛書](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mawangdui_Silk_Texts)</kbd><kbd>[東漢](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Han_dynasty#Eastern_Han)
隸
[image: 愛]
郙閣頌</kbd>
　<kbd>[西晉](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jin_dynasty_(266%E2%80%93420))
隸
[image: 愛]
徐美人墓志</kbd>
　
<kbd>楷
[image: 愛]</kbd>

「旡」 was later corrupted into 「⿱爫冖」, forming 「愛」. Sometimes, 「心」 and 「夊」 were also shuffled around; if 「心」 is moved to the bottom left, it is written as 「忄」.

---

The character in question,

[image: 愛]

retains the non-corrupted 「旡」

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

and shuffles 「心」 to the bottom left.

<kbd>[image: 愛]</kbd>

---

**References:**

- [小學堂](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/)

  - [字形演變](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/yanbian)
  - [異體字表](https://xiaoxue.iis.sinica.edu.tw/variants)
- [漢語多功能字庫](http://humanum.arts.cuhk.edu.hk/Lexis/lexi-mf/)
- [中國社會科學院考古研究所《殷周金文集成》](http://www.guoxuedashi.com/yzjwjc/)

Answer (score 2):

These four characters are "牧者所爱" in Clerical script font.

"牧者所爱" is a title of a Hymn. The English title is "DEAR TO THE HEART OF THE SHEPHERD," written by Ma­ry B. Win­gate.